# redis keep expireAt, would it guarantee to be expired?

Tags: redis

I want to use a key to limit request count per second（RPS），I want the key to be expired every seconds, so it would like:

```
if($redis->get($key) > 10){
    // reject
}else{
    $redis->incr($key);
    $redis->expire($key, 1);  // one second later would be a new key
    // accept
}
```

This would cause problem, because every requests wound refresh the expire, so the key would never expired.

So if I change it to:

```
$redis->expireAt($key, time() + 1);  // absolute time, expired at the beginning of next second
```

I don't know if this would do the trick.

Will the key guarantee to expired at that time? Or may be if the request happens exactly at the beginning of next second,it would be refreshed too?

PS：Offical Docs used if check and expire in a script, but I just want to know  if expireAt without script would do. Thks.

### EDIT

I'll try to make an example.

Now it's 23:50:51，each request in this second will issue expireAt 23:50:52，so if it's accurate, the key would expire at that time, when the time comes at 23:50:52, the request would make expireAt 23:50:53, but in theory the key should be just expired, so it's still a new key, which do the trick without multi-keys or script

Comment: When you call next `expireAt`, `time()` will hold a new value, won't it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev will not if in the same second

Comment: The key will live for a full another second, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev notice the 'expireAt', not 'expire', see my comment under your answer

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I thought that expiration happens at the end of a second. Not sure why I'd think that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying only on expire, embed the timestamp in the key name.

For example using key=`rl:YYYY:MM:DD:HH:SS` instead of key=`rl` allows you to expire the key but have each new second create a new key. The expiration is used here for keeping the dataset small, not for limiting the increment calls to a time window. Limiting the increment calls to a time window with per-second resolution is easily accomplished by isolating the resolution using the key name.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution.. I just want to know if we can use expire without multi key pattern, the official docs showed these two ways

Comment: You can use it however you want, but It wont do what you say you want done. There is a good reason the docs showed the ways it works. ;)